# Как правильно конвертировать int в binary?

Tags: java

Есть несколько способов получить бинарное значение с int

вот один из коробки

```
Integer.toBinaryString(value);
```

Но этот метод возвращает значение в котором от 7 до 9 знаков, не пойму от чего это зависит

Я вот нашел подход как получить из int бинарное значение которое всегда возвращает 8 знаков

```
private static void printByte(int value) {
    String currentBinary = Integer.toBinaryString(256 + value);
    System.out.println(currentBinary.substring(currentBinary.length() - 8));
}
```

1. Насколько я понимаю в бинарном значении должно быть 8 знаков, почему
   тогда в методе который предложен из коробки постоянно то 7 то 9
   знаков и если нужно привести это к одному виду то нужно делать вот
   так как в примере выше
2. Почему прибавляем 256, а не другое число? Я понимаю, что это
   максимальное значение для UInt но почему именно оно берется?

И в итоге все равно потом `substing` подрезает строку до нужной длины...

В общем все как то не ясно) Хочу понять как это работает, а не просто запомнить как факт.

Comment: связанные вопросы: [How to get 0-padded binary representation of an integer in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421400/4279) и [Left pad zeroes to a string variable in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7970615/4279)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Но этот метод возвращает значение в котором от 7 до 9 знаков, не пойму от чего это зависит

Метод `Integer.toBinaryString(...)` возвращает строковое представление переданного числа в двоичной форме **без** лидирующих нулей.

Например:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1));
// вывод: 1

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(2));
// вывод: 10

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(16));
// вывод: 10000
```

По второму вопросу:

`256` в десятичной системе счисления – это `1_0000_0000` в двоичной. Если к этому числу прибавить **меньшее** (по абсолютной величине) число, то ведущая единица останется на месте, следовательно, идущие после нее нули в строке гарантированно будут. Ну а потом строка обрезается до нужной длины.

Вообще говоря, приведенный метод работает некорректно, например:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(12345));
// вывод 11000000111001
printByte(12345);
// вывод 00111001
```

Добавить лидирующие нули, можно, например, [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421438/7129209):

```
String s = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(1)).replace(' ', '0');
```

Comment: Вся ясно теперь) Но все равно как то странно, что java предлагает метод `toBinaryString()` который подразумевает, что число которое туда будет передано конвертируется в бинарное представление, зачем убирать лидирующие нули не понятно... Чтоб потом самому форматировать строку для получения в итоге нормального результата?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Видимо у каждого свое представление нормального результата.